# PySide Error: Type Error for grouping buttons: only accepts 1 arguments, 1 given

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside

I am trying to group buttons so that I can detect if a member of a button group is being clicked

For example:

If we have button1 and button2, and they are both in buttonGroupA, I would like to know if buttonGroupA is clicked or not, below is an implementation suggested in a stackoverflow post

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class ButtonGroup(QtCore.QObject):
    trigger = QtCore.Signal(bool)

    def addButton(self, button):
        button.clicked.connect(self.trigger.emit)

    def removeButton(self, button):
        button.clicked.disconnect(self.trigger.emit)




# In state class

    self.displayGroupButton = group_button.ButtonGroup()

# In display class

    testButton = QtGui.QPushButton("testing", self._container)
    self.state.displayGroupButton.addButton(testButton)
    grid.addWidget(testButton, 0, 7)
```

The thing is that if I have

```
 self.state.displayGroupButton.addButton(testButton)
```

and clicked the button, the following error shows up

```
TypeError: trigger(bool) only accepts 1 arguments, 1 given!
```

If I don't have

```
self.state.displayGroupButton.addButton(testButton)
```

There is no error

Can somebody explain to me why is it exhibiting this behavior?

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason, but the answer to your original question had this line: `trigger = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)`, not your: `trigger = QtCore.Signal(bool)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I believe the original solution was referring to PyQt4, and the altered solution is referencing PySide

Comment: There is already `QButtonGroup`... Why are you re-implementing that?